# Split a String with delimiter - , (comma) and double quotes over every value in java

Tags: java, string, split

I have a String value as -
["My, fancy, text", "My, other, value"]

I want to get the output as a List with elements as -

```
My, fancy, text
My, other, value
```

The enclosing bracketts are to be removed.It may happen that enclosing bracketts '[' and ']' are not present.
'

Comment: And the problem is?

Comment: What is the actual output list?  You've shown us text...but that's not a Java list.

Comment: O/p has to a List<String> containing values -
My, fancy, text - first value in list

My, other, value -  second value in list

Comment: With the brackets in place, that appears to be JSON, so you could try using a JSON parser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the requirement is to remove all the square brackets and finding text between double quotes as individual string. Below Code might help

```
        String[] data = Stream.of(
            input.replaceAll("\\[", "")//replace all [
            .replaceAll("\\]","")//replace all ]
            .replaceAll("\",","")// replace the comma between strings,
            .split("\""))//now split the string based on double quotes
            .filter(str ->str.trim().length() > 1)//filtering out the string which contains only whitespace
            .toArray(String[]::new);//collecting the data in an array

    //data[0] = My, fancy, text
    //data[1] = My, other, value
```

Comment: Please accept the answer, if you have got what you are looking for :)

Answer (score 0):

```
My own solution is not very elegant thats the problem
public static void main(String []args){
        String s = "[\"I,my,me\", \"We,our,us\"]";
        if(s.startsWith("[") && s.endsWith("]")) {
            s = s.substring(1, s.length() -1);
        }
        System.out.println(s);
         for (String a : s.split("\"")) {
             if(!a.isEmpty() && !a.equals(","))
            System.out.println(a);
         }
     }
```

Comment: Rather than System.out.println() i can add it to list and return it.But it looks a bit lengthy way